# How to make background gradient fill the screen which is applied to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css, frontend

Okay, this is my layout. The `section` part is a partial and loaded into the screen dynamically with AngularJS when /login route is loaded. Now, I want to have a `background-image` gradient property on `section` and I want that gradient on the whole screen. How can I do that?

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <main ng-view>
   <section class="login">
     <form>...</form>
   </section>
  </main>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add that gradient to body?

Comment: @LimH. I cant do that because the login partial will be loaded dynamically using angularjs. And the whole body has a single css file.

Comment: Why not adding a class to the body then apply a gradient on this class?

Comment: can you position:fixed; that section?

Comment: can you create a div with 100% width to wrap section and then apply gradient to that div? With your HTML would be the `main`, but I don't know what are you using that for

Comment: @Veve Thats nice but I want to do this without adding javascript

Comment: Without JS?  You're already using AngularJS.  I would consider doing it with some very simple vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something link the following in your css

```
.login{
  overflow:hidden; /* this may or may not be required */
  background: /* details of section background here */
}

html{
  background: /* details of page background here */
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @AbhinandanN.M. is this close to what you are after? http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/emYgyJ

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class to `<body>`, then add style with your section, you can have a complete gradient background without javascript :

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body class="bg">
  <main ng-view>
   <section class="login">
     <style type="text/css">
       .bg{
            background: linear-gradient( red, blue);
       }
     </style>
     <form>...</form>
   </section>
  </main>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want the gradient only on the login page. I dont want that in my dashboard which also resides in the same `body`. The login page will be loaded dynamically at runtime using angularjs

Comment: I don't understand... The style you'll apply on body will be applied only when charged dynamically with your section. If the section isn't loaded, there won't be any style applied.

Answer (score 0):

This little js snipped solved my problem. I think it is practically impossible to achieve this without using js.

```
$('#first').height(function(index, height) {
    return window.innerHeight - $(this).offset().top;
});
```